# Copying Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magento-1.4

Ive got two seperate installations of Magento.

The old installation is Magento 1.4 and the new installation is 1.9.

There are about 1200 categories on the old one. I want to re-create them perfectly (including IDs) on the new one.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the database structure is the same (which I doubt between those versions) you can use a query to import / export. Otherwise, tools normally create new IDs so that's not an option. Another option when the database structure differs is to upgrade the 1.4 to a 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There´s a extension that make this as an export.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html

I think it´s the best way for this amount of products.

Comment: just so I have a better understanding, what are the other ways of doing this?